# My $_REQUEST variables have carriage returns as their first characters

Tags: request, trim

I have a website on a windows server (with Apache 2.2 and PHP5.3). This website is also installed on another server.

On one server only, I must do `trim( $_REQUEST['example'] )` because the received variables have invisible new line or carriage returns as their first character.

Do you have a idea what can be wrong ( php config, Apache config, ...)?